# javascript regex find words contains (at) in text

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a bunch of strings to browse and find there all words which contains **"(at)"** characters and then gather them in the array.

Sometimes is a replacement of **"@"** sign. So let's say my goal would be to find something like this: **"account(at)example.com"**.

I tried this code:

```
let gathering = myString.match(/(^|\.\s+)((at)[^.]*\.)/g;);
```

but id does not work. **How can I do it?**

I found a regex for finding email addresses in text:

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi)
```

I think about something similar but unfortunately I can't just replace `@` with `(at)` here.

Comment: @gurvinder372 You are using unescaped parentheses in your pattern, and it won't behave as desired.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Agree, though OP hasn't mentioned if `()` will only be around `at` or can it be mentioned anywhere else as well or not.

Comment: @gurvinder372  Hey I was thinking about whole set of chars _(at)_ in the same place, inside a word. It dosen't matter if _()_ will appear somewhere else in the string.

Comment: I found a regex for finding email addresses in text: `/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi)` I think about something similar but unfortunately I can't just replace "@" with "(at)" here :)

Comment: You have a working regex with `@`, and replacing it with correctly escaped `(at)` will solve the issue. You just need to escape `(` and `)` to match these chars literally.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew you mean something like:  `/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+(at)[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi)` ? I don't know exactly how to specify this set of chars into regex. Im kinda newbie in this topic

Comment: Reads the linked post. `(` and `)` are special. `(at)` matches `at` and puts the value into Group x. You need to escape `(` and `)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var longString = "abc(at).com xyzat.com";
var regex = RegExp("[(]at[)]");
var wordList = longString.split(" ").filter((elem, index)=>{
    return regex.test(elem);
})
```

This way you will get all the word in an array that contain "at" in the provided string.

Comment: It catches all of the `at` in string. However  not only (at) but every word contains "at" as well (e.g cat, what...ect). Do you know how can I catch only `(at)`? I tried with your code var `regex = RegExp("at");` but it doesn't work

Comment: yes its very simple check the updated code below;-
var longString = "abc(at).com xyzat.com";
var regex = RegExp("[(]at[)]");
var wordList = longString.split(" ").filter((elem, index)=>{
    return regex.test(elem);
})

Answer (score 0):

You could use `\S+` to match not a whitespace character one or more times and escape the `\(` and `\)`:

[`\S+\(at\)\S+\.\w{2,}`](https://regex101.com/r/ayiMZy/1/)